# WSOD when trying to configure menu with many items

Tags: 7, routes, performance, wsod

I have a menu with *many* nested/multi-lingual menu items (I don’t know the exact number, probably something around 2000-3000).

Whenever I try to visit its configuration page in the backend (`/admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-foobar`), I get a [WSOD](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) after some loading time.

The site is hosted on a shared webhost (PHP memory limit is at `256M`; max execution time at `120`), so I assume it might work to move to a more powerful VPS, but I wonder:

Is there any way to access the menu configuration page without moving to a better server or changing the site architecture (i.e., using several menus instead of one)?

I tried the [**Menu Admin Splitter** module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menuadminsplitter), but it didn’t help.

Comment: Did you check your server logs?

Comment: 2-3 _thousand_ menu items? With the best will in the world, you're doing something terribly wrong there. The obvious performance problems aside, making users wade through that many items, or even a percentage of them, is decidedly bad UX. I'd recommend coming up with a different solution for your users to browse the site, Drupal's menu system isn't going to be very forgiving here. If you still want to go down your current route, we'll need to know what error message the WSOD is causing. You can find this in your server logs, if you could edit it into the question that would be graet

Comment: @KrishnaMohan: I fear I don’t have access to those kind of server logs (I can only see access logs). I could try to "Enable Error Reporting" (as described on the [WSOD](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) page), but it’ll take some time. I’ll bump-comment when I have it.

Comment: @Clive: I can assure you that the UX is not affected ;) It’s a multi-lingual site with many languages, so users only see menu items in their language (still "many" nodes, but in a manageable amount). The problem is that I "trusted" the multi-lingual menu features, instead of creating separate menus per language. (For the error log part, see my comment above). -- Accessing this menu worked when the site only had a few languages, but after more languages (= more nodes = more menu items), the WSOD came. -- So when I’d restart building the site, I could circumvent it, but can’t do it currently.

Answer (score 1):

A fiddly **workaround**:

On the "list links" menu page, you can visit, rearrange, enable/disable, edit, and delete all menu items. Except for visiting the node, all this is possible from a single menu item’s edit page.

But how to access the menu item edit page without being able to access the parent’s menu page listing all those items?

1. Visit the node whose corresponding menu item you want to edit.
2. Open its HTML source code.
3. Search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) for `active menu-mlid`. You’ll find a `class` value like `menu-mlid-218`. `218` is the menu item ID.
4. Visit `/admin/structure/menu/item/218/edit`.

Comment: Interesting challenge, and even more interesting work-around! Just a thought about another variation of this work-around: there has to be a Drupal table that contains the data like that "218". So starting from there, I'd build an SQL statement to retrieve the relevant data (with relevant joins to related tables). Then use [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) to create an appropriate report about that, which would also include an hyperlink for each row (result) to point to that 218/edit-like link. And use "datatables" to enable client site searching for nodes. Worth a real answer?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Not sure if I’ll get the chance to try it on the site in question anymore (was not my site), but I’ll certainly be interested to read your answer about your workaround -- who knows, maybe there are others out there with the same problem :)